# Getting function into TI-83 calculator trouble

Tags: calculator

I'm trying to get

$$y = -0.1t^2 + 1.2t + 98.6, \quad0 \le t \leq 12 $$

into my TI-83 calculator to graph it, but I'm having trouble figuring out the correct syntax for this one. What it would be? I tried something like $0\le x\le 12$ then the equation, and every other combo of things I could think of but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first go to "mode" and set the calculator to parametric. After that, you press the Y= button and set X=T (the variable, not the letter) and Y=-0.1T^2 + 1.2T + 98.6. Go to 2nd: Quit and then press window, setting the Tmin and Tmax for 0 and 12, respectively. Set the increment for whatever you want and then press graph, and you should be good to go.